# RTSP play extention with mov,3gp and mp4 in iOS SDK

Tags: ios, rtsp

I'd like to `stream ,play video` from `RTSP` url

rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_175k.mov with also in 3gp,mp4

i have download [test code](https://github.com/mooncatventures-group/RTSPPlay)
this is working fine with `rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_175k.mov` but not able to play with `3gp` and `mp4`

can we `play` `video` with `audio` ?

Comment: please explain, the extension doesn't mean very much when actually decoding the video. so what do you mean does not play with 3gp and mp4. The bigbuckbunny video is encoded in 2 channel aac / h264 . rtspplay should play that video without issue. We would need more detail on your particular problem.

Comment: As i wanna develope Application which run rtsp url video with format of mov,3gp and mp4 rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_175k.mov this mov url

Answer (score 1):

look at this  project for some hints

https://github.com/mooncatventures-group/WebStreamX_flv_demo/

Its similar to the other gits but shows how to play a video locally, also answered similar question on the github issue log for you

Comment: thanks for answer but i have download this and there is some files are missing such as config.h and plist that i am not able to test rtsp url, if you tested then can you share with me , thanks ins advance

Comment: config.h and plist are no longer needed and can be safely removed.